# delete rows matrix R containing NaN

Tags: r, matrix, nan

I import a table into R using:

```
mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv")
```

Some of the cells of the table are undefined, I convert them to NaN.

```
mydata[mydata == "<undefined>"] <- NA
```

I would like to find the indeces of the rows containing NaN for the column 4 and delete the corresponding rows (across all the table).

Could you please help me?

In matlab I would do:

```
idx_rows_nan = find(isnan(mydata(:,4)));
mydata(idx_rows_nan,:)=[];
```

Comment: just filter instead of deleting: `m[!is.na(m[,4]),]`

Comment: `NA` is not the same as `NaN`.

Comment: @Roland I mean not a number...

Comment: I know what `NaN` means. But you assign `NA` in your code, which is probably what you want anyway.

Comment: @Roland I am very new to R (always used Matlab) I wanted to assign the equivalent of NaN in Matlab... What does NA mean?

Comment: `NA` denotes a missing value. It has always a type (e.g., `character` or `numeric`). That's usually what you want. You seem to know what `NaN` denotes. Read `help("NA")` and `help("NaN")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `is.na()` (with a dot)

```
mydata[!is.na(mydata[,4]),]
```

In two steps, one could first identify the rows containing `NA` in column 4 by defining a logical vector `na_rows`:

```
na_rows <- is.na(mydata[,4])
```

The row numbers with `NA` in column 4 can be displayed with `which(na_rows)`

Then one could remove these rows with

```
mydata <- mydata[!na_rows,]
```

If you want to identify `NaN` entries instead of `NA`, the function `is.nan()` can be used.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I would like to have a 2 step approach since I am interested on viewing the indeces

Comment: I wouldn't use `-` as this may return `0` rows if there are no NaN in the column 4.  It might be better to use `!`.  As an example, `mydata <- data.frame(Col1= 1:4);mydata[-is.nan(mydata[,1]),, drop=FALSE]
#[1] Col1
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names); mydata[!is.nan(mydata[,1]),, drop=FALSE]`

Comment: As pointed by Roland I should find NA values...not NaN...sorry... is there a is.missing function?

Comment: It works the same way with `is.na()` (without "n" at the end).

Comment: If `mydata[!is.na(mydata[,4]),]` and `which(is.na(mydata[,4])` don't yield the desired results, I would suggest that you post a sample of your data. It may then be a matter of the variable class and it could help to see the structure of your data.

Comment: Given all the help of @Roland and @ akrun, I decided to post this as a community wiki. Hope this is alright for you.

Comment: @RHertel That's nice of you, but not really necessary. I've got so much rep that I don't care about it anymore.